# configure docker variables with ansible

Tags: docker, ansible, containers

I have a docker image for an FTP server in a repository, this image will be used for several machines, I need to deploy container and change `PORT` variable depending on the destination machine.

This is my image (I've deleted lines for proftpd installation cause it is not relevant to this case):

```
FROM alpine:3.5

ARG vcs_ref="Unknown"
ARG build_date="Unknown"
ARG build_number="1"

LABEL org.label-schema.vcs-ref=$vcs_ref \
  org.label-schema.build-date=$build_date \
  org.label-schema.version="alpine-r${build_number}"

ENV PORT=10000
COPY assets/port.conf /usr/local/etc/ports.conf
COPY replace.sh /replace.sh
#It is for a proFTPD Server
CMD ["/replace.sh"]
```

My `port.conf` file (Also deleted not relevant information for this case)

```
# This is a basic ProFTPD configuration file (rename it to
# 'proftpd.conf' for actual use.  It establishes a single server
# and a single anonymous login.  It assumes that you have a user/group
# "nobody" and "ftp" for normal operation and anon.

ServerName          "ProFTPD Default Installation"
ServerType          standalone
DefaultServer           on

# Port 21 is the standard FTP port.
Port                {{PORT}}
.
.
.
```

And `replace.sh` script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

[ -z "${PORT}" ] && echo >&2 "PORT is not set" && exit 1
sed -i "s#{{PORT}}#$PORT#g" /usr/local/etc/ports.conf

/usr/local/sbin/proftpd -n -c /usr/local/etc/proftpd.conf
```

... Is there any way to avoid using replace.sh and use ansible as the one who replace `PORT` variable in `/usr/local/etc/proftpd.conf` the file inside the container?

My actual ansible script for container is:

```
- name: (ftpd) Run container
  docker_container:
    name: "myimagename"
    image: "myimage"
    state: present
    pull: true
    restart_policy: always
env:
  "PORT": "{{ myportUsingAnsible}}"
networks:
  - name: "{{ network }}"
```

Resuming all that I need is to use Ansible to replace configuration variable instead of using a shell script that replaces variables before running services, is it possible?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `docker_container` module which will need a pre-built image. The file `port.conf` is baked inside the image. What you need to do is set a static port inside this file. Inside the container, you always use
the static port `21` and depending on the machine, you **map** this port onto a different port using ansible.

Inside `port.conf` always use port `21`

```
# Port 21 is the standard FTP port.
Port                21
```

The ansible task would look like:

```
- name: (ftpd) Run container
  docker_container:
    name: "myimagename"
    image: "myimage"
    state: present
    pull: true
    restart_policy: always
networks:
  - name: "{{ network }}"
ports:
 - "{{myportUsingAnsible}}:21"
```

Now when you connect to the container, you need to use the `<hostnamne>:{{myportUsingAnsible}}`. This is the standard docker way of doing things. The port inside the image is static and you change the port mappings based on the
available ports that you have.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, that's correct in case I need to change port, although, I need to change other variables also... What I need is to detect if there is any posibility to use a template inside image and change variables with ansible

Comment: @AlvaroNiño Ansible can change files on the host machine and not directly inside the container. You can thus have the file on the machine, template it using ansible `template` module and mount the file onto the container. This will make the templated file accessible by the container.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I'll do that... is the best option... Due security reasons I was requested to have configuration file inside container, although I think is not posible to have it as `template` inside container

Comment: It is doable, however you will get into a chicken-egg problem. You can connect through ansible into a **running** container using `docker exec` commands.